# Capture an uncapturable error

Tags: r

I want to capture an error from `D%4` and move on. The error is:

```
Error: unexpected input in "D%4"
```

Typically if a function is being called the following works:

```
capture_warn_error <- function(x){
    tryCatch({
        x
    }, warning = function(w) {
        w
    }, error = function(e) {
        e
    })
}

capture_warn_error(D%4)
```

But the no recovery is possible as `D%4 shuts down everything immediately:

```
## > capture_warn_error(D%4)
## Error: unexpected input in "capture_warn_error(D%4)"
```

Is there anyway to capture such a stubborn beast and move on?  I know `D%4` isn't an object but this works for other non objects:

```
capture_warn_error(means)
## <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): object 'means' not found>
```

It's be nice to:

1. Understand why `D%4` is unrecoverable vs `means`
2. Find a way to recover still and capture `D%4`'s error

Comment: That's a parse error, not an error thrown by something like `stop`. I'm not sure how you would catch something like that, short of capturing the expression and evaluating it manually.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich can it be handled?  I'm guessing not since this won't work: `as.character(substitute(D%4))`

Comment: @Benjamin `D%4` is just arbitrary gibberish causing the parser to throw an error, which the OP wants to catch; if I understand correctly.

Comment: @Benjamin Nothing the point is it throws an error.

Comment: @nrussel Precisely but it may be that as  a parse error it's not possible to handle.

Comment: What would you want the function to continue doing in this case, since the error is in the input?  You could catch it with `sink()` (my deleted answer), then if that error occurred you could add backticks to  the input and try again? .. or something.

Comment: @RichardScriven I'm looking to help new R users who get an error to know what to do.  So if I captured the error I'd know it was a typo (parse error of some sort and make recommendations with regard to that).

Comment: In that case, some sort of input capture like [swirl](http://swirlstats.com/) might be useful

Answer (score 5):

As others have stated it is because text typed at the console gets passed to the  parser. `D%4` fails the rigid test of being valid R expression, because a single `%` is not valid inside an R name (although it would create a token that would be interpreted as a user defined function if there were a closing `%`) and `%` is also not a function name (although`%%` is). The error occurs in the processing of the argument to your function and so it never reached the internal `tryCatch`-call.  I originally didn't get the idea that you wanted to parse this input as R code, so thought that simply wrapping `readline` as the single argument to be be input may satisfy:

```
mfun <- function( x=readline(">>+ ") ){ print(x) }
mfun()
#-----screen will display--------
>>+ D%4
[1] "D%4"
```

If I'm wrong about your intent, as it appears on a re-read of the question, then this would build that input mechanism into your capture_error function. This brings those characters in as unparsed text and then does the parse-eval within the `tryCatch` enclosure:

```
> capture_warn_error <- function(x=readline(">>+ ")){
+     tryCatch({ eval(parse(text=x))
+         
+     }, warning = function(w) {
+         w
+     }, error = function(e) {
+         e
+     })
+ }
> capture_warn_error(D%4)
Error: unexpected input in "capture_warn_error(D%4)"
> capture_warn_error()
>>+ D%4
<simpleError in parse(text = x): <text>:1:2: unexpected input
1: D%4
     ^>
> err <- capture_warn_error()
>>+ D%4
> err
<simpleError in parse(text = x): <text>:1:2: unexpected input
1: D%4
     ^>

> err <- capture_warn_error()
>>+ D %% 4
> err
<simpleError in D%%4: non-numeric argument to binary operator>
> err <- capture_warn_error()
>>+ 4 %smthg% 2
> err
<simpleError in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "%smthg%">
```

As demonstrated above, it does require that you not provide any input in the argument list to the function call, but rather make the capture-call with an empty argument list.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a function to capture input and parse it, wrapping it in your capture_warn_error function.

```
getfunction <- function(){
  x<-readline()
  if(x == "exitnow"){return("bye!")}
  print(capture_warn_error(eval(parse(text = x))))
  getfunction()
}
```

They'll now be typing at a non-console prompt, but it will work okish - assignments will need work.

```
1+1
[1] 2
d%e
<simpleError in parse(text = x): <text>:1:2: unexpected input
1: d%e
     ^>
exitnow
[1] "bye!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this works for capturing the error, although it's a bit convoluted.

```
a <- try(eval(parse(text="D%4")))
```

Comment: The problem is you can't really get this far with `capture_warn_error(D%4)` because you can't grab the argument `x` from `capture_warn_error` when it is `D%4`.